# Get one list of lists from N lists of lists, and sometimes a list also

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm still learning Scheme.

If have these two list of lists:

```
'((1 2 (3 4) 5) (12 13 4))
'((3 4 9) (7 6 5 4))
```

I want to get this list:

```
'((1 2 (3 4) 5) (12 13 4) (3 4 9) (7 6 5 4))
```

But with `cons`:

```
(cons '((1 2 (3 4) 5) (12 13 4)) '((3 4 9) (7 6 5 4)))
```

I get this list:

```
'(((1 2 (3 4) 5) (12 13 4)) (3 4 9) (7 6 5 4))
```

**NOTE**:

In this example the both lists has two sublists. But they can have n sub-lists.

I have tried with `append` but it doesn't work when one of the list of lists is only a list:

```
(append '(1 2 3 4) '((23 24 25 26) (a b c)))
> '(1 2 3 4 (23 24 25 26) (a b c))
```

Is there a function that do it or do I have to implement it?

Comment: What do you mean "`append` doesn't work when one of the lists of lists is only a list"? The behavior of `append` does not depend on a list's elements. `(append '((1 2 (3 4) 5) (12 13 4)) '((3 4 9) (7 6 5 4)))` yields the expected `'((1 2 (3 4) 5) (12 13 4) (3 4 9) (7 6 5 4))`

Comment: Look at the code bellow that paragraph.

Comment: @VansFannel If you did not like `'(1 2 3 4 (23 24 25 26) (a b c))`, then you should define what you want instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using car and cdr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511191/using-car-and-cdr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior that you want is very specific, you won't find it in the standard library. Good news is, it's simple to implement in a portable and efficient way that covers all the possible cases, assuming that the input lists are non-empty:

```
(define (my-append lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((and (pair? (car lst1)) (pair? (car lst2)))
         (append lst1 lst2))
        ((pair? (car lst1))
         (append lst1 (list lst2)))
        ((pair? (car lst2))
         (append (list lst1) lst2))
        (else
         (append (list lst1) (list lst2)))))
```

For example:

```
(my-append '((1 2 (3 4) 5) (12 13 4)) '((3 4 9) (7 6 5 4)))
=> '((1 2 (3 4) 5) (12 13 4) (3 4 9) (7 6 5 4))

(my-append '(1 2 3 4) '((23 24 25 26) (a b c)))
=> '((1 2 3 4) (23 24 25 26) (a b c))
```

Comment: How about `(my-append '((1 2) 3 4) '((23 24 25 26) (a b c)))`? Just guessing, but since `((1 2) 3 4)` does not qualify as list of lists, OP probably want to get `(((1 2) 3 4) (23 24 25 26) (a b c))` but not `((1 2) 3 4 (23 24 25 26) (a b c))`.

Comment: Well, then OP should really, really post a good set of tests of what he wants and stop making people guess what convoluted functionality he needs each time ;)

Comment: Yes, the OP is very annoying.