# In DrRacket how do i alter my program that uses if statements to rather use a conditional statement

Tags: string, list, substring, racket

Here is the question I am trying to solve

> Write a function `(last-substring-len s n)`.
>
> It consumes a Str and a Nat, and returns the substring of s with
>   length n that comes last alphabetically.
>
> Remember to consider if your function Requires anything of its
>   arguments!
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> (last-substring-len "foobar" 4) => "ooba"
>
> (last-substring-len "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogs" 7) => "xjumpso"
> ```

I have actually nearly solved my question but I want to be able to instead alter my code so that the if statements for the function get-maximium are replaced with cond statements.

This is my original code:

```
(define (substrings-w-len s n)
  (cond
  [(> n (string-length s)) '()]
   [ else (cons (substring s 0 n)
            (substrings-w-len (substring s 1 (string-length s)) n))]))


(define (get-maximium string-list)
  (if(null? string-list) '()
  (if(= 1( length string-list)) string-list
  (if (equal? #true (string>=? (first string-list) (first (rest string-list))))
                  (get-maximium (cons (first string-list) (rest (rest string-list))))
                  (get-maximium (rest string-list))))))

(define (last-substring-w-len s n)
  ( get-maximium (substrings-w-len s n)))

(check-expect (last-substring-w-len "foobar" 4) "ooba")
```

This yields `(list "ooba")` when it should only yield "ooba" so I need to convert the list into a string which I should be able to solve myself but i'd appreciate if someone could help me with this.

The main issue now though is i want to replace the if statements in get-maximum with a conditional statement

This is me altering the get-maximium function to try to replace the if functions with a cond statement but it doesn't work yet.

```
(define (get-maximium string-list)
  (cond
  [(null? string-list) '()]
  [(= 1( length string-list)) string-list]
  [ else (equal? #true (string>=? (first string-list) (first (rest string list))))
                  (get-maximium (cons (first string-list) (rest (rest string-list))))
                  (get-maximium (rest string-list))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with the `else` part. It should look like this:

```
(define (get-maximium string-list)
  (cond [(null? string-list) '()]
        [(= 1 (length string-list)) string-list]
        [(string>=? (first string-list) (first (rest string list)))
         (get-maximium (cons (first string-list) (rest (rest string-list))))]
        [else (get-maximium (rest string-list))]))
```

Also, there's no need to ask `(equal? #t <condition>)`, simply ask `<condition>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve the first element of the answer like so:

```
(define (last-substring-w-len s n)
  (first ( get-maximium (substrings-w-len s n))))

(last-substring-w-len "foobar" 4) => "ooba"
(last-substring-w-len "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogs" 7) => "xjumpso"
```

For a thorough explanation see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511191/using-car-and-cdr/45521852#45521852)