# Return something enclosed in parentheses in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, church-encoding

I have the following piece of code for the successor and predecessor of Church numerals:
Consider the following code:

```
(define zero (lambda () '() ))   ; Initialize Church numeral zero as nil
(define (succ x) (lambda () x))  ; Wraps x with another function and returns it
(define (pred x) (x))            ; "Unwraps" one shell function of x and returns it

(define one (succ zero))         ; gives me the Church numeral one
(pred one)
```

Suppose I do the following changes in the pred function:

```
(define (pred x) x)
```

What is the difference between returning x and (x)? What exactly does returning (x) mean syntactically and logically?

Comment: These don't look like Church numerals to me... are they a different encoding of numbers into lambdas? How does this different encoding work? By that I mean, how can you use one of these lambda-encoded numbers in a program to compute something?

Comment: In this context, `x` is a `lambda` used to represent a numeral and `(x)` is an _application_ of that `lambda`- a function call.

Comment: They are Church numerals because each number n has been represented as a nesting of n functions

Comment: Maybe you're misunderstanding Church numerals. In Object-oriented terms, Church numerals are represented by the method "repeat-N-times". For example if `N` is the church numeral 4, then `(N f x)` repeats `f` 4 times, returning `(f (f (f (f x))))`. `(N f x)` can be thought of as `N.repeat-N-times(f, x)`. What you have seems like a different encoding of numbers into lambdas, different from Church numerals. Is your question about the "repeat-N-times" notion of Church numerals, or is it about your "nested-lambda-nil" encoding shown in your code?

Comment: I guess it is "nested-lambda-nil"

Comment: Read this for thorough list explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511191/using-car-and-cdr/45521852#45521852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function

```
(define (pred x) x)
```

is the identity function. The function accepts a value and binds it to the argument `x`. It then evaluates the body `x` which gives the original value back.

The function

```
(define (pred x) (x))
```

takes one value as input and binds it the argument `x`.
It then evaluates the body `(x)`. The expression `(x)` means call (the hopefully a function) `x` with no arguments.

```
(pred (lambda () 42)) will evaluate to 42.
```

So in the context of your encoding `(lamdda () x)` wraps a function layer a value and `(x)` removes the function layer.